# What order the same event will fire if it is captured in several modules?

Tags: magento-1.7, event-observer

I want to listen to an event by using an observer in my module. There are some other module observers as well which are listening the same event. So is there any particular order of firing the observer functions for this event? Or can I set is through the code to fire my modules observer function after some other observer function?

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way you can set order of the observers on the events is by module dependencies.
For example if you have one observer in the module `Ns1_Module1` and one in `Ns2_Module2` and you want the one in `Ns2_Module2` to be fired first, you need to make `Ns1_Module1` depend on `Ns2_Module2` in `app/etc/modules/Ns1_Module1.xml`

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Ns1_Module1>
            <depends>
                <Ns2_Module2 />
            </depends>
        </Ns1_Module1>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: So there are no other alternative ways to do this? I knew this way. But didn't aware that this is the one and only way. Thanks a lot. Assume if we haven't provided this <depends> tag in module activation file, in that case which order will Magento fire the event observers?

Comment: @Su123 The observers will fire in the order they are loaded when initializing the config. Most probably in the alphabetical order of the files from `app/etc/modules`. This could be an other way to sort them. If you want the event from `N1_M1` to fire later that `N2_M2` just name the declaration file for `N1_M1` to something else that is lower in alphabetical order than `N2_M2`. But I wouldn't go that way. It's becomes hard to manage.

Comment: The order is determined in Mage_Core_Model_Config by $moduleFiles = glob($etcDir . DS . 'modules' . DS . '*.xml'); The documentation on this function does not mention it but I my tests the sort order has been alphabetically http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/magento-extension-clashes-winners-and-loosers/ - the depends nodes are factored in a bit later.

Answer (score 5):

If no dependencies are given, the order will be the alphabetical list of module-descriptions loaded from within *app/etc/modules/*.